# gcloud command changes ownership of the current directory

Tags: gcloud, kubectl

I'm performing usual operation of fetching kubernetes cluster credentials from GCP. The `gcloud` command doesn't fetch the credentials and surprisingly updates the ownership of the local directory:

```
~/tmp/1> ls
~/tmp/1> gcloud container clusters get-credentials production-ng
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) Unable to write file [/home/vladimir/tmp/1]: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/vladimir/tmp/1'

~/tmp/1> ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

Other commands, like `gcloud container clusters list` work fine. I've tried to reinstall the `gcloud`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens if your `KUBECONFIG` has an empty entry, like `:/Users/acme/.kube/config`
gcloud resolves the empty value as the current directory, changes permissions and tries to write to it

Reported at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143911217

Comment: the issue was linked to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140786118 and closed as won't fix :( so you need to be aware that your `KUBECONFIG` does not include empty entries

Answer (score 3):

It happened to be a problem with `kubectl`. Reinstalling it solved this strange issue.

If you, like me, have stuck with strange `gcloud` behavior, following points could help to track an issue:

- Checking `alias` command and if it's really pointing to the intended binary;
- Launch separate docker container with `gsutil` and feed it your config files. If the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...` runs smoothly there, than it's the problem with binaries (not configuration):

```
docker run -it \
       -v $HOME/.config:/root/.config \
       -v $HOME/.kube:/root/.kube google/cloud-sdk:217.0.0-alpine sh
```

- Problem with binary can be solved just by reinstalling/updating;
- If it's a problem with configs, then you could back them up and reinstall [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) / [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) from scratch using not just `apt-get remove ...`, but `apt-get purge ...`. Be aware: `purge` removes config files!

Hope this would help somebody else.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Running `gcloud components update` worked for me, *but* only after a restart of my machine. So, if you try this and it doesn't work, try a restart!